# How do I specify the Play Framework to use a different route file

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm aware that I can make the Play server use a different application.conf file by using the -Dconfig.file flag.

Is there any way to also specify the server to use a different route file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set it in your application.conf or use the JVM flag

`-Dapplication.router=my.application.Routes`

https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.2.1/framework/skeletons/java-skel/conf/application.conf#L20

```
# Router
# ~~~~~
# Define the Router object to use for this application.
# This router will be looked up first when the application is starting up,
# so make sure this is the entry point.
# Furthermore, it's assumed your route file is named properly.
# So for an application router like `conf/my.application.Router`,
# you may need to define a router file `my.application.routes`.
# Default to Routes in the root package (and `conf/routes`)
# application.router=my.application.Routes
```

Comment: Can a route file includes another route file, just like application.conf can?

Comment: Yes a real life example is in https://github.com/beligum and see http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/SBTSubProjects "splitting the routes file".